# How to use code splitting with webpack in react app with components exported as export * from '...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use code splitting in my react app and overall it works great, but I noticed something strange in bundle analyzer. My components folder is loaded in the first chunk with all its components (even the ones that are only used in lazy loaded components).

I think the problem is that I follow the structure of using index.ts files to export my components:
/components:

- /Component1

  - /Child1

    - Child1.tsx
    - index.ts
  - Component1.tsx
  - index.ts
- /Component2

  - Component2.tsx
  - index.ts
- index.ts

The index.ts files just export the needed components like so

```js
export * from './Component';
```

this is the same as

```js
import { Component } from './Component';

export { Component };
```

in javascript.

By doing it that way I get very nice looking imports:

```js
import { Component } from 'components';
```

without the deep paths and all that stuff.

But i think because of that webpack can not recognize how to split it and just bundles it all.

Are there any solutions for this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I use the default create react app config right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
export * from './Component';
```

This is causing webpack to bundle all the components which are there in `'./Component'` and whatever it importing and so on.

You should export components individually without using `*`

Like `export { Component1, Component2 } from './Component'`

Also if you are using Webpack 5, it creates a mapping of which component import is used and discard unused components. This is not available in Webpack 4.

Comment: I just tried to change the exports to what you suggested and it didn't help, the components folder still is one module with all used (even in the lazy loaded parts) components

Comment: @ZVER3D Please add the code snippet where you are trying to create multiple chunks.